# Text to Speech from Service

Tags: android

I have a service running on device boot. It checks for some data and send out Notifications.
I came across the following.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-the-text-to-speech-engine/

and I want to send voice notification. I do not need UI part of it. How do I add it in my project?

1. Differnt java class (calling Activity from service)
2. An internal class

Answer (score 1):

Create class `App` and an instance of `TextToSpeech` in it:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static TextToSpeech mTts;

    public static TextToSpeech getmTts() {
        return mTts;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // creating TTS:
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        mTts.stop();
    }
}
```

Declare `App`(above) in your manifest:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="your.application.package.App" >
```

Send a `broadcast` by your service when you want to a `BroadcastReceiver` for example this:

```
public class TTSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mTts = App.getmTts();
        mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        message = "your message";
        mTts.stop();
        mTts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I just wanted to comment and upvote for the static approach. I was playing around with interfaces, services, the new "TextToSpeechService" and what not. Almost no Examples found. Really frustrating. Didn't use the "Application" mentioned, just created a static TextToSpeech outside my Activity and now all fragments can happily access it, with a helper class. Don't even need a broadcast

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SpeakService extends Service implements OnInitListener {

     public static TextToSpeech tts;
     private String string;

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate() {
         tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
         super.onCreate();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() {
         if (tts != null) {
             tts.stop();
             tts.shutdown();
         }
         super.onDestroy();
     }

     @Override
     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);
       string = intent.getStringExtra("string");
     }

     @Override
     public void onInit(int status) {
       if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
         int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
         if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.d("SpeakService", "Language is not available.");
         } else {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
                speak(string);
            } else {

                speak("Error");
            }
         }
       } else {
        Log.d("SpeakService", "Could not initialize TextToSpeech.");
     }
     }

     private void speak(String string) {
        tts.speak(string, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
     }
```